# MarshMallow Permission dialog doesn't prompt

Tags: android

In Marshmallow the runtime permission dialog doesn't promt again if first time the permission is denied.
I have to 3 dangerous permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,READ_SMS & CAMERA permission.
Can anyone tells me where i'm going wrong.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                } else {   
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
                }
            }
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                } else {

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
                }

            }
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {

                } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_SMS);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: where is your AlertDialog.Builder code ??

Comment: is your code at oncreate();?

Comment: within onViewCreated of a fragment @Hasmukhkachhatiya

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use

`requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, Constants.RESULT_CODE);`

instead of

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
                                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code it may helps you**

> Use this code where you want to open permission request dialog.

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 2);
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, 3);


        }
```

> Below code is used for handling permission dialog response(Open permission dialog again and permission check granted or denied etc.)

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
                }
                else{
                    Log.e("permission force:", "Here you code if anyone check never and denied request of Write External Storage");

                }
            }

        } else if (requestCode == 2) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 2);

                }else{
                    Log.e("permission force:", "Here you code if anyone check never and denied request of Camera");


                }
            }
        }else if (requestCode == 3) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_SMS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)) {

                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS}, 3);

                }else{
                    Log.e("permission force:", "Here you code if anyone check never and denied request of ReadSMS");


                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the more confusing aspects of the runtime permissions API is the `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` is only intended to be used when you get `PERMISSION_DENIED` in your `onRequestPermissionsResult()` callback. Doing so in other places can lead to strange behavior.

Your best bet is to check for a permission needed and request it,  if your app doesn't have it. In the result handle the denial, if needed.

You may find this helper library easier to deal with as it handles this for you and also helps your app follow the Google guidelines for ui: https://github.com/hiqes/andele